# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4n^4+1}$ converges to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4n^4+1}$$
my attempt :
assumed the series is a telescopic and tried finding $t_n - t_{n-1}$ but then realized it is not a telescopic series. $$$$ //answer is given to be 0.25

Answer (score 5):

Use the factorization:
$$\dfrac{n}{4n^4+1} = \dfrac{n}{(2n^2-2n+1)(2n^2+2n+1)} = \frac 14\cdot\dfrac{1}{2n^2-2n+1}-\frac 14\cdot\dfrac{1}{2n^2+2n+1}$$